# filter rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c(0, 0, 01, 02, 03, 011, 012, 013, 0111, 0112, 0113),
                  x1 = rnorm(11), 
                  x2 = rnorm(11),
                  x3 = rnorm(11))


my.df <- data.frame(id = 0, id1 = 01, id2 = 011, id3 = 0111, some.column = 'xyz')
```

I want to filter rows from `dat` using following conditions:

If `my.df$id3` is present in `dat$id`, filter `dat$id == my.df$id3`, if not
check if `my.df$id2` is present and filter `dat$id == my.df$id2`, if not,
check if `my.df$id1` is present and filter `dat$id == my.df$id1`, if not
simply filter `dat$id == my.df$id`

```
dat %>% 
dplyr::filter(ifelse(my.df$id3 %in% id, id == my.df$id3, 
              ifelse(my.df$id2 %in% id, id == my.df$id2,
              ifelse(my.df$id1 %in% id, id == my.df$id1, id == my.df$id))))
```

It returns null rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for or how does your expected output look like? In the example below the filter `id == my.df$id3` is applied if `my.df$id3` is present in `dat$id`. Since this is the case, this filter leaves only one row of your original data.

```r
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(id = c(0, 0, 01, 02, 03, 011, 012, 013, 0111, 0112, 0113),
                  x1 = rnorm(11), 
                  x2 = rnorm(11),
                  x3 = rnorm(11))


my.df <- data.frame(id = 0, id1 = 01, id2 = 011, id3 = 0111, some.column = 'xyz')

dat %>% 
  dplyr::filter(if (my.df$id3 %in% id) {
                  id == my.df$id3
                } else if (my.df$id2 %in% id) {
                  id == my.df$id2
                } else if (my.df$id1 %in% id) {
                  id == my.df$id1 })
#>    id        x1         x2         x3
#> 1 111 0.3771992 -0.5073165 -0.3555985
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Yes. I expect a single row to be returned. This is correct

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the column values in `my.df` the required order to create `order_vec`, filter values present in it, `arrange` the values and select the first row.

```
library(dplyr)

order_vec <- unlist(my.df[c(paste0('id', 3:1), 'id')])

dat %>%
  filter(id %in% order_vec) %>%
  arrange(match(id, order_vec)) %>%
  slice(1L)

#   id  x1    x2    x3
#1 111 1.5 0.872 0.848
```